# Joomla 3.2 security breach

Tags: php, image, security, joomla

I have the following problem on a joomla 3.2 site.

I developed the site on localhost environment using xampp with no problems.

When I moved the site on a live server it got hacked. The hacker used the the core function from joomla (add image) to insert a script that hacked the entire server.

The hacker renamed the script into a .jpg or .png extension and was able to upload it on the server. My confusion is that on localhost I am unnable to upload a script renamed into a .jpg or .png extension because it says "invalid image type", however on the live site I can upload anything as long as I rename the file with an image extension.

**My question is:**

- How come is this possible on the live server to do this and on my localhost not?
- Are there any issues with the server configuration?

PS: I checked the `"add image"` code on the localhost environment and on the live server and everything is the same.

The server is Apache with PHP 5.3.28.

Also I want to add that before the site was hacked the file permissions where screwed up. Now the folders are 755 and files are 644.

Thanks

Comment: Please submit this security issue to the Joomla Github Repository and once a solution is found, I'm sure it will be fixed in the next update.

Comment: I suppose the live server was badly configured.

Comment: ok change your editor use jceEditor tinymce and ckeditor have bug!!

Comment: @samankhademi - Where are you getting this information from, can you confirm from a source?

Comment: @lodder check upload controller.php in tiny

Comment: @samankhademi - please specify the location as I have no idea where you're referring to. Please also specify which bit of code/the line number in the file.

Comment: Make sure you are on current Joomla and that you have not given the public permission to upload images in the media manager.

Comment: We can't do this on our live or development sites so you've either misconfigured the installation or there are serious configuration issues with your server.

Answer (score 1):

There is/was a pretty coordinated hack based on this same principle.  We now check all plugins and add-ons before installing.

http://blog.fox-it.com/2014/11/18/cryptophp-analysis-of-a-hidden-threat-inside-popular-content-management-systems/

https://foxitsecurity.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/cryptophp-whitepaper-foxsrt-v4.pdf

We weren't affected, but I ran across this StackOverflow when I was googling the event in the process of explaining to a user why all add-ons have to be scanned and approved before I install them.